# Representing $\mathbb{N}$ as the union of countable collection of noninterscting countable sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I vaguely remember solving this problem before. I also vaguely remember the solution had something to do with prime numbers.It makes sense, since the primes are enumerable, and we can express any natural as a product of primes.

If we didn't have the nonintersecting condition, the solution would simply be that the sets are $$A_p = \{np: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ where $p$ is a fixed prime.

If I remember correctly, a slight modification on that solves the problem so I'm looking for a hint.

Or perhaps there's another solution not involving primes at all.

Comment: You may want $n$ to not be  anything already in an $A_q$ with $q <p$.  There are  other solutions too, for example looking at powers of $2$ but not other primes

Comment: Hint: Consider prime factorizations.

Comment: Another approach: divide $\Bbb N$ into just two countably infinite sets, and then recursively subdivide one of them in the same way.

Comment: I'll try both approaches. Soon I'll post an attempted solution.

Comment: What if you look at the highest power of a fixed prime that divides each number?

Comment: When you use the word "countable", do you mean "countably infinite"?  (I ask, as many authors will use "countable" to mean "there exists an injection from the set to the natural numbers", hence a finite set is also considered countable).

Comment: I mean "countably infinite". The author from the book I'm currently reading distinguishes between finite and countable.

Comment: another interesting answer: $0,2,4,6,..., 1,3,7,13,19,27,...,5,9,15,23,..., 11,17,25,...,\dots$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Sketch of Solution:}$

Let $$A_1 = \{n\in\mathbb{N}: 2\mid n\},$$
$$A_2 = \{n\in\mathbb{N}: 3\mid n\text{ and } n\not\in A_1\}, $$
$$A_3 = \{n\in\mathbb{N}: 5\mid n\text{ and } n\not\in A_1,A_2\}.$$

In general, if $p_j$ is the $j$-th prime, then
$$
A_j = \{n\in\mathbb{N}: p_j\mid n\text{ and } n\not\in A_1,A_1\cdots A_{j-1}\}.
$$

There's an enumerable quantity of primes, so there's an enumerable quantity of such sets. Moreover, since $\mathbb{N}$ is enumerable, each $A_j$ is enumerable, for $p_j^n\in A_j$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. By construction $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ whenever $i\neq j$.

So $$\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}A_j$$ is the desired representation of $\mathbb{N}.$